# Skype closes when I try to update my profile picture

Tags: 18.04, skype

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using the Cinnamon desktop. I recently downloaded Skype (not from the terminal). I have an interesting problem when I try to change my profile picture, Skype just shuts down.

Everything else seems to be working fine. But when I try to change my profile picture the whole program shuts down. If I reopen it, I have to log in again. All my software are up to date. I've only been using Linux for a few days.

How can I get this issue fixed, please?

Comment: If you launch Skype from Terminal, you'll probably see some error messages when it closes.